# Performing recursion but the code is running twice

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to perform recursion but the code is running twice. How to break recursion loop? I want it to run only once. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
x = 5
def my_fun():
    global x

    if x == 5:
        print('x is 5')
        x = 3
        my_fun()

    print('x is 3')

my_fun()
```

**Expected Output**

- x is 5
- x is 3

**Output from code**

- x is 5
- x is 3
- x is 3

Comment: What is your goal with this function? Is it to take an odd number and decrement 2 from it everytime till it's three? or just to print 5 and 3 which can be done with normal non-recursive code

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using recursion for this? But ok. Anyway, using parameters is a better way to do it than `global`.

```
def my_fun(x):
    if x >= 3:
        print(x)
        x-=2
        my_fun(x)

my_fun(5)
```

Comment: This is not the original code I was facing this issue in. I was using a function in my code where I was facing a similar issue like this. This is like a prototype to help me solve the issue and it did.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `else` in `my_func` when `x!=5`  to get the expected output

```
>>> x= 5
>>> def func():
...     global x
...     if x ==5:
...             print('x is 5')
...             x = 3
...             func()
...     else:
...             print('x is 3')
... 
>>> func()
x is 5
x is 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_fun():
    global x
    if x == 5:
        print('x is 5')
        x = 3
        my_fun()
    else:
        print('x is 3')

my_fun()
```

Answer (score 0):

On your initial call, x = 5 and "x is 5" is printed. x is changed to 3.

Then the function calls itself.

The if clause is false, so only "x is 3" is printed.

The recursion returns and the initial call is continued. "x is 3" is printed.